# What is blocking my ip address when I do a Jmeter stress test?

Tags: ubuntu, jmeter

I have written a test in Jmeter. 500 threads are released on the homepage of my site with a ramp-up period of 1 second. I have whitelisted my ip address with the command:

```
sudo ufw allow from *myipaddress*
```

The test runs fine for the first 250 threads and after that there is a connection timeout. The site is no longer accessible with my normal ip address. When I change my ip to something else the site is accessible. After several minutes I can access the site with my normal ip again. The site is hosted on Ubuntu 18.04. The logs in /var/log/syslog and /var/log/apache2/error.log show no errors.

Now that I have whitelisted my ip address with ufw I wonder what is still blocking my ip address?

Comment: Could it be that you have overwhelmed your server? Have you talked to your hosting company about this? (They might see it as a DoS attack)

Comment: How could I access the site with a different ip address if the server were overwhelmed?

Comment: The hosting provider blocking your IP address on the router is a very plausible explanation. What have you done to rule this out? What does the network topology between you and your server look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be anything, not knowing the details of your infrastructure setup between load generator machine and application under test (including routers and switches), any interim software used (reverse proxies, load balancers), configuration of middleware (database, application server) it is not possible to come up with the reason.

The first thing you should do is to inspect state of TCP sessions on the load generator and application under test using [netstat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) command or equivalent.

Another thing to check is system/kernel logs as it might be the case the [packets are being filtered by the kernel](http://antmeetspenguin.blogspot.com/2011/01/high-performance-linux-router.html)

As a workaround you can go for [IP aliasing](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-creating-or-adding-new-network-alias-to-a-network-card-nic/) and [configure JMeter in such a way so each thread (virtual user) would have its own IP address](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter), potentially it might help to overcome the issue.

Comment: When I use a different ip than the one from my provider I am not blocked... Apparently my own provider/router is blocking.